# Sql Server Stored Procedure calling seasonal package in R

Tags: sql-server, r, stored-procedures

I have written SQL server stored procedures using R functions. All work without issue from Sql Server Management Studio with one exception.

I want to use the seasonal package however the code in Sql Server Management Studio fails. The same code works absolutely fine within R (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS\R_SERVICES\bin).

```
Sys.setenv("X13_PATH" = "C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS/R_SERVICES/library/x13binary/bin");
require(seasonal);
seasonal::checkX13()
```

(I've included the X13_PATH here as it is necessary for the sql server R to work - it is not required when run from my desktop R).

The error message displayed is:

```
STDERR message(s) from external script: 
Loading required package: seasonal
X-13 installation test:
  - X13_PATH correctly specified
  - binary executable file found
  - command line test run successful
  - command line test produced HTML output

Error : seasonal test run failed, with the message:
Error : X-13 has run but produced no data

Error details:
  - X13_PATH:         C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS/R_SERVICES/library/x13binary/bin
  - Full binary path: "C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS/R_SERVICES/library/x13binary/bin/x13ashtml.exe"
  - Platform:         x86_64-w64-mingw32
  - R-Version:        R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
  - seasonal-Version: 1.1.0
```

Exactly the same code run from R in the sql directory returns:

```
X-13 installation test:
  - X13_PATH correctly specified
  - binary executable file found
  - command line test run successful
  - command line test produced HTML output
   - seasonal test run successful
Congratulations! 'seasonal' should work fine!
```

I granted permissions on these folders for Full Control (for R, for R library folders, for the x13 binary folder), in the hope that this would resolve the issue but it still fails...

Any ideas on how to solve this please?

Comment: Root Cause: The data file created as a temporary file by executing the external R script in sqlserver has a very LONG name. This path is specified in the .spc file read by x13ashtml.exe process which sets the limit for the data file name to be 133.

Comment: Create a symbolic link to the ExtensibilityData folder
mklink /d c:\extensibilitydata-<full instance name> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\ExtensibilityData"

e.g. mklink /d c:\extensibilitydata-MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\ExtensibilityData"  

Edit C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\rlauncher.config,
Set WORKING_DIRECTORY to be this newly created symbolic link.

e.g.

WORKING_DIRECTORY=C:\extensibilitydata-MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER

Comment: Restart the Sql Server Launchpad Service. In an elevated command prompt execute: net stop mssqllaunchpad & net start mssqllaunchpad

Answer (score 2):

The answer has been submitted in the comments above.

Comment: You should put the answer in, well, your answer. Comments aren't guaranteed to stick around.